# What triggered the popularity of lambda functions in modern mainstream programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, history, lambda

In the last few years anonymous functions (AKA lambda functions) have become a very popular language construct and almost every major / mainstream programming language has introduced them or is planned to introduce them in an upcoming revision of the standard.

Yet, anonymous functions are a very old and very well-known concept in Mathematics and Computer Science (invented by the mathematician Alonzo Church around 1936, and used by the Lisp programming language since 1958, see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function)).

So why didn't today's mainstream programming languages (many of which originated 15 to 20 years ago) support lambda functions from the very beginning and only introduced them later?

And what triggered the massive adoption of anonymous functions in the last few years? Is there some specific event, new requirement or programming technique that started this phenomenon?

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

The focus of this question is the introduction of **anonymous functions** in modern, main-stream (and therefore, maybe with a few exceptions, non functional) languages. 
Also, note that anonymous functions (blocks) are present in Smalltalk, which is not a functional language, and that normal named functions have been present even in procedural languages like C and Pascal for a long time.

Please do not overgeneralize your answers by speaking about "the adoption of the functional paradigm and its benefits", because this is not the topic of the question.

Comment: 15-20 years ago people were asking the same question about OO... it wasn't a new concept but it had an explosion of popularity.

Comment: @MattDavey: As far as I can remember, one of the factors that boosted the adoption of OO techniques was the growing popularity of GUI's, which were easier to implement using OO techniques. But, seriously, did anyone come up with a reasonable explanation?

Comment: @Giorgio I think the explanation for OO's proliferation is Java. While today Java might not be the first choice for most of us, back then it was an extremely cool platform. The concept might not have been new, but until Java it wasn't really supported, at least not in a way that was appealing to the majority of professional developers. The concepts were there, but we were missing the tools that would help us utilize the concepts in a way that's almost immediately productive. And I think the same thing is happening now, with functional programming.

Comment: @YannisRizos I think most Smalltalk developers would disagree with your assertion that Java is responsible for popularizing OO ;)

Comment: @MattDavey Most would certainly disagree, but then I'd have to remind them that "most Smalltalk developers" isn't really that many people ;P

Comment: I think the more interesting question is what triggered their *demise*! After all, there was a time, when most modern languages *did* have lambdas, then languages like Java and C++ became popular. (Although I wouldn't exactly call Java a "modern" language. The most modern concept in Java is Generics, which dates back to the late 60s/early 70s. Even the *combination* of features Java provides, pointer safety, memory safety, type safety, GC, statically typed OO, Generics all existed in Eiffel in 1985 … and much better, IMHO.)

Comment: Even before Java 1.0 came out, while it was still in the early design stages, pretty much everybody pointed out that Java needs lambdas. Some of the designers that worked on Java include Guy Steele (Lisp proponent, co-designer of Scheme, co-author of Common Lisp, designer of Fortress), James Gosling (wrote the first Emacs Lisp interpreter for PCs), Gilad Bracha (Smalltalk proponent, co-designer of Animorphic Smalltalk, designer of Newspeak), Phil Wadler (co-designer of Haskell), Martin Odersky (designer of Scala). How Java ended up without lambdas is really beyond me.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: I did not know about this! Maybe they made this choice because there were not sure if lambdas would have been accepted by the mainstream developer community (at the time it was mainly Pascal, C, and C++). I would appreciate if you could write your observations in an answer, they are very informative.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Regarding Java being modern, I think Java owed its success to Sun's support and adoption, thus making existing ideas popular. And having a large standard library was also a big booster: after all, many programmers (or at least I) spend more time binding existing libraries together than writing their own code. I am pretty sure that if a big company decided to boost any existing language (Common Lisp, Smalltalk, Eiffel, ...), that language would become mainstream within a few years.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Java does have lambdas. They are just have a different name because you can not have bare functions in Java. But the same functionality is available via  `anonymous classes`. http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm

Comment: @Loki Astari: I often thought that anonymous classes are Java's (purely object-oriented) version of lambdas (since a language without functions cannot have anonymous functions, you need some form of anonymous objects). Then what is the fuss about adding lambdas in Java all about? Syntactic sugar?

Comment: @Giorgio: Yes it is just syntactic sugar. From JSR 335 (Highlighting mine): `A functional interface is **an interface** that has just one abstract method, and thus represents a single function contract.` The same affect is achieved via anonymous classes (just a tiny bit more typing is involved).

Comment: "A tiny bit" often means 50% function, 50% noise.

Comment: @Giorgio: The more important thing is a set of standard function interfaces in the standard library, and library methods that accept those function interfaces. Interestingly, Scala's support for functional programming is about the same as Java's: functions are "faked" with objects that have only a single method. The difference with Java is 1) that method has a standardized name (`apply`), 2) there are standardized interfaces in the std lib (`Function1`, …), 3) there are methods taking those types as arguments (`map`, …), 4) there is a tiny bit of syntactic sugar.

Comment: The syntactic sugar, however, is not that important. What *is* important is the standardization. I can create a predicate function and pass that function to a collection for filtering and to an ORM and to a GridView and … because all of them take a `Function1[T, Bool]`. In Java, I cannot do that, because the collection takes a `Predicate<T>`, the ORM takes a `HibernateFilter<T>`, the GridView takes something else and so on. (I made these types up, BTW, but the problem exists.) Neal Gafter said that he counted over 20 incompatible copies of a function interface in the Java 5 std lib.

Comment: "Scala's support for functional programming is about the same as Java's: functions are "faked" with objects that have only a single method.": I know only a little Scala but I am not sure if this is the case: in Scala you have currying, algebraic data types and pattern matching, type inference, i.e. lots of features typical of FP that are missing in Java.

Comment: @Giorgio Java's function can not close over mutable variables, only eventually final variables. That's one of the difference between "real" closures (e.g. smalltalk) and "fake" syntactic suggar closure. Whether closing of mutable variable is good or bad is another issue. Java's designers argue this restriction is actually good, since closing over mutable state lead to sequential code. See http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-4.html

Comment: @ewernli in practice I found it very useful that I can access non-final (writable) variables in the enclosing scope. c# lambdas, Groovy closures know this.

Comment: @Karl: Uncontrolled non local side effects: this seems the antithesis of functional thinking to me.

Comment: @kevin kline: '"A tiny bit" often means 50% function, 50% noise.' How much of the total Java code is anonymous functions? 2%? In such a case the new syntactic sugar would allow to save 1% of the total typing.

Comment: @Giorgio: The reason Java code is only 2% anonymous functions is because the syntax is so awkward everyone avoids them.  If the syntax were reasonable, they would be used very frequently (see LISP, Javascript, Groovy, Ruby, Perl, Scala, etc.)

Comment: @Giorgio: the problem is not the typing, it's the time wasted thinking of and writing the noise, and the much greater time spent reading around it.

Comment: @kevin cline: I agree with you and I am a fan of anonymous functions (e.g. in Scala and Haskell). I wonder how they can be added to Java. As a special syntax for one-method anonymous classes? How do they affect the Java type-system? Will some kind of type inference be needed? Will they really boost productivity without extending the standard collections appropriately? If the addition of lambdas should cause deep language changes, why not continue to use plain old Java for OOP and a real functional language (e.g. Scala or Clojure) for FP? Feels a bit like reinventing the wheel to me.

Comment: @ewernli: Thanks for the interesting link. From that page: "it is quite difficult to write lambda bodies like this that do not have race conditions. Unless we are willing to enforce—preferably at compile time—that such a function cannot escape its capturing thread, this feature may well cause more trouble than it solves." I somewhat agree that capturing non final variables can be quite dangerous and contrary to functional thinking (even though the use of closures does not automatically imply functional programming).

Comment: Is Java responsible for popularizing OO? Smalltalk aside, I remember Delphi aficionados used to talk a lot about how their version of OO is more real OO compared to VB, while everybody else was looking down on multiple inheritance in C++. I would say that, at the time of introduction of Java, OO was *already* the biggest trend in software development then.

Comment: @Muhammad Alkarouri: Sure. There was Pascal with objects (and more or less at the same time, C++). Java came a few years later when many programmers had already moved to OO.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There's certainly a noticeable trend towards functional programming, or at least certain aspects of it. Some of the popular languages that at some point adopted anonymous functions are C++ ([C++11](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)), PHP ([PHP 5.3.0](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)), C# ([C# v2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)), Delphi (since 2009), Objective C ([blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)) while [Java 8 will bring support for lambdas to the language](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/lambda/) . And there are popular languages that are generally not considered functional but supported anonymous functions from the start, or at least early on, the shining example being JavaScript.

As with all trends, trying to look for a single event that sparked them is probably a waste of time, it's usually a combination of factors, most of which aren't quantifiable. [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), published in 2005, may have played an important role in bringing new attention to Lisp as a *practical* language, as for quite some time Lisp was *mostly* a language you'd meet in an academic setting, or very specific niche markets. JavaScript's popularity may have also played an important role in bringing new attention to anonymous functions, as munificent explains in [his answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/173489/25936).

Other than the adoption of functional concepts from multi-purpose languages, there's also a noticeable shift towards functional (or mostly functional) languages. Languages like Erlang (1986), Haskell (1990), OCaml (1996), Scala (2003), F# (2005), Clojure (2007), and even domain specific languages like R (1993) seem to have gained a strong following strongly after they were introduced. The general trend has brought new attention to older functional languages, like Scheme (1975), and obviously Common Lisp.

I think the single more important event is the adoption of functional programming in the industry. I have absolutely no idea why that didn't use to be the case, but it seems to me that at some point during the early and mid 90s functional programming started to find it's place in the industry, starting (perhaps) with [Erlang's proliferation in telecommunications](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1238844.1238850) and [Haskell's adoption in aerospace and hardware design](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_in_industry).

Joel Spolsky has written a very interesting blog post, [The Perils of JavaSchools](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html), where he argues against the (then) trend of universities to favour Java over other, perhaps more difficult to learn languages. Although the blog post has little to do with functional programming, it identifies a key issue:

> Therein lies the debate. Years of whinging by lazy CS undergrads like me, combined with complaints from industry about how few CS majors are graduating from American universities, have taken a toll, and in the last decade a large number of otherwise perfectly good schools have gone 100% Java. It's hip, the recruiters who use "grep" to evaluate resumes seem to like it, and, best of all, there's nothing hard enough about Java to really weed out the programmers without the part of the brain that does pointers or recursion, so the drop-out rates are lower, and the computer science departments have more students, and bigger budgets, and all is well.

I still remember how much I hated Lisp, when I first met her during my college years. It's definitely a harsh mistress, and it's not a language where you can be immediately productive (well, at least I couldn't). Compared to Lisp, Haskell (for example) is a lot friendlier, you can be productive without that much effort and without feeling like a complete idiot, and that might also be an important factor in the shift towards functional programming.

All in all, this is a good thing. Several multi-purpose languages are adopting concepts of paradigm that might have seemed arcane to most of their users before, and the gap between the main paradigms is narrowing.

Related questions:

- [Functional Programming on the rise?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71287/functional-programming-on-the-rise)
- [Why isn't functional programming more popular in the industry? Does it catch on now?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49/why-isnt-functional-programming-more-popular-in-the-industry-does-it-catch-on)
- [Why hasn't functional programming taken over yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835801/why-hasnt-functional-programming-taken-over-yet)

Further reading:

- [Why are functional programming languages, especially Common Lisp and Lisp dialect Clojure, making a comeback in popularity?](http://www.quora.com/Why-are-functional-programming-languages-especially-Common-Lisp-and-Lisp-dialect-Clojure-making-a-comeback-in-popularity)
- [Functional Programming: What caused the rise in popularity of functional programming?](http://www.quora.com/Functional-Programming/What-caused-the-rise-in-popularity-of-functional-programming)
- [Can Your Programming Language Do This?](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html)
- [Why functional programming? Why Haskell?](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/why-functional-programming-why-haskell.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and lots of interesting ideas). +1 Yet, I would argue that introducing (only) lambdas into a programming language is a very small step towards FP, and it may even be confusing to many (what are lambdas doing all alone inside an imperative language?). After learning some Haskell, Scala, and SML, I do not have the feeling I can do real FP with an imperative language that only supports lambdas (what about currying, and pattern matching, immutability?).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6316/discussion-between-giorgio-and-yannis-rizos)

Comment: @YannisRizos:  Perl's had anonymous functions since the first release of 5 (1994), but they weren't completely "right" until 5.004 (1997).

Comment: @penartur That's what I thought too, but a friendly editor corrected me by pointing me here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: I think that perhaps the main "event" that brought about the popularity of functional languages is the web. More specifically, the shift from desktop programs to server side. This gives the developer freedom to choose any programming language. Paul Graham and Lisp in the 90s is a notable example.

Answer (score 31):

I think its interesting how much the popularity of functional programming has paralleled the growth and proliferation of Javascript. Javascript has a lot of radical features along the functional programming spectrum that at the time  of its creation (1995) were not very popular among mainstream programming languages (C++/Java). It was injected suddenly into the mainstream as the only client-side web programming language. Suddenly a lot of programmers simply had to know Javascript and therefore you had to know something of functional programming language features.

I wonder how popular functional languages/features would be if it had not been for the sudden rise of Javascript.

Comment: Javascript is surely an important language, but I am not sure if the introduction of Javascript can account for the popularity of functional programming on its own: a lot of other functional programming languages have appeared over the last years, as Yannis has illustrated in his answer.

Comment: @Giorgio - there might've been a lot of other functional programming languages, but (relatively) nobody uses them. The use of JS and the increased view that the C++/Java way of making functors is painful and annoying are really the driving forces to the mainstream, even if the more academic languages firmed up how they should be implemented.

Comment: The popularity of dynamic languages in general is hinted at as one explanation for the popularity of Haskell: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/why-functional-programming-why-haskell.html#id572991

Comment: Also, the focus of the question is not the popularity of FP in general, but about the **late introduction** of anonymous functions in general-purpose, non functional languages. Even if the big public (most programmers) did not know them, language designers knew them very well. There must have been a reason for leaving them out at the beginning. Maybe they were considered non-intuitive for the developers of the early 90-ties.

Comment: @giorgio - They're far more troublesome to implement as opposed to Java style functors. Combine that with the lack of knowledge/adoption and it's a pretty clear design choice.

Answer (score 27):

JavaScript and DOM event handlers meant that millions of programmers *had* to learn at least a little bit about first class functions in order to do *any* interactivity on the web.

From there, it's a relatively short step to *anonymous* functions. Because JavaScript doesn't close over `this`, it also strongly encourages you to learn about closures too. And then you're golden: you understand anonymous first class functions that close over enclosing lexical scopes.

Once you're comfortable with it, you want it in every language you use.

Comment: +1 it's not just about anonymous functions. Closures are a much broader concept than just defining a temporary function inline.

Comment: @phkahler: You are right and, in this sense, Java already has closures (and even more powerful than what you get with a function literal) but it lacks a concise notation for the common case of a one-method anonymous class.

Answer (score 17):

It certainly isn't the *only* factor, but I'll point out the popularity of Ruby. Not saying this is more important than any of the six answers already on the board, but I think that many things happened at once and that it's useful to enumerate them all.

Ruby is not a functional language and its lambdas, prods, and blocks seem clunky when you've used something like ML, but the fact is, it popularized the notion of mapping and reducing to a generation of young programmers fleeing Java and PHP for hipper pastures. Lambdas in several languages seem to be defensive moves more than anything else ("Stick around! We've got those too!!)

But the block syntax and the way it integrated with .each, .map, .reduce and so forth popluarized the idea of an anonymous function even if it's really a syntactic construct that behaves like a coroutine. And the easy conversion to a proc via & makes it a gateway drug for functional programming.

I argue that Ruby on Rails programmers writing JavaScript were already turned on to doing things in a lightweight functional style. Couple that with programmer blogging, the invention of Reddit, hacker News, and Stack Overflow around the same time, and the ideas spread faster over the Internet than they did in the days of Newsgroups.

TL;DR: Ruby, Rails, JavaScript, blogging, and Reddit/Hacker News/Stack Overflow pushed functional ideas to a mass market, so everyone wanted them in existing languages to prevent further defections.

Comment: +1 For a good answer and (if I could, because I only have one upvote) +1 for pointing out that "Lambdas in several languages seem to be defensive moves more than anything else ("Stick around! We've got those too!!)". I think this is a factor too. For some languages lambdas are a nice-to-have feature which, even though it adds very little expressive power to the language as a whole, it gives the language some popularity (a number of programmers seem to think that support for anonymous functions is equivalent to fully supporting functional programming).

Comment: I really think this is the reason why most languages have implemented block syntax in the recent years. But the only way to make sure is to ask he language developers what their motives were. We can only speculate imo.

Comment: for me, Ruby is the language that first made blocks *rock* and very appealing, so +1. Haskell might have had an effect as well.

Answer (score 14):

As [Yannis](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/173442/22493) pointed out, there are a number of factors that have influenced the adoption of high-order functions in languages that were previously without. One of the important items he only touched lightly on is the proliferation of multi-core processors and, with that, the desire for more parallel and concurrent processing.

The map/filter/reduce style of functional programming is very friendly to parallelization, allowing the programmer to easily make use of multiple cores, without writing any explicit threading code.

As Giorgio notes, there is more to functional programming than just high-order functions. Functions, plus a map/filter/reduce programming pattern, **and** immutability are the core of functional programming. Together these things make for powerful tools of parallel and concurrent programming. Thankfully, many languages already support some notion of immutability, and, even if they don't, programmers can treat things as immutable allowing the libraries and compiler to create and manage asynchronous or parallel operations.

Adding high-order functions to a language is an important step to simplifying concurrent programming.

**Update**

I'll add a couple more detailed examples in order to address the concerns Loki noted.

Consider the following C# code which traverses a collection of widgets, creating a new list of widget prices.

```
List<float> widgetPrices;
    float salesTax = RetrieveLocalSalesTax();
foreach( Widget w in widgets ) {
    widgetPrices.Add( CalculateWidgetPrice( w, salesTax ) );
}
```

For a large collection of widgets, or a computationally intensive CalculateWidgetPrice(Widget) method, this loop would not make good use of any available cores. To do the price calculations on different cores would require the programmer to explicitly create and manage threads, passing work around, and collecting the results together.

Consider a solution once high-order functions have been added to C#:

```
var widgetPrices = widgets.Select( w=> CalculateWidgetPrice( w, salesTax ) );
```

The foreach loop has been moved into the Select method, hiding its implementation details. All that remains to the programmer is to tell Select what function to apply to each element. This would allow the Select implementation to run the calculations in parellel, handling all the synchronization and thread management concerns without the programmer's involvement.

But, of course, Select does not do it's work in parallel. That's where immutability comes in. The implementation of Select does not know that the provided function (CalculateWidgets above) does not have side effects. The function could change the state of the program outside the view of Select and its synchronization, breaking everything. For example, in this case the value of salesTax could be changed in error. Pure functional languages provide immutability, so the Select (map) function can know for sure that no state is changing.

C# addresses this by providing PLINQ as an alternative to Linq. That would look like:

```
var widgetPrices = widgets.AsParallel().Select(w => CalculateWidgetPrice( w, salesTax) );
```

Which makes full use of all the cores of your system without explicit management of those cores.

Comment: I do point to the desire for more parallel and concurrent processing, it's discussed in the "A history of Erlang" ACM article I'm linking to in the fourth paragraph. But it's a very good point, and I should have probably expanded on it a bit more. +1 because now I don't have to ;P

Comment: You're right, I didn't look carefully enough. I edited my remark.

Comment: Oh, you didn't really have to do that, I wasn't complaining ;)

Comment: None of what you describe above requires lambdas. The same functionality is achieved just as easily with named functions. Here you are simply documenting a `cause` and a `perceived affect` without explaining the `correlation`. The last line IMO is what the question is about; but you did not answer it. Why does it simplify concurrent programming.

Comment: @Ben: Be careful that your example concerns higher-order functions which do not need anonymous functions to be used. Your answer contains interesting ideas (for another question) but is going off topic right now.

Comment: @Giorgio perhaps it's not detailed too clearly because I think to Ben the correlation is obvious though not to all readers. The correlation is that lambda's are generally a technique for creating closures which are invaluable for CPS. Granted they aren't a requirement and using delegates one has been able to create closures in C# for a long time, but there is a track record of using lambda's for closures going back a very long time so as parallelism and distributed processing grew so too did CPS for concurrency and remote asynchrony, and therefore closure usage grew, so lambda desire grew.

Answer (score 9):

I agree with many of the answers here, but what's interesting is that when I learned about lambdas and jumped on them, it wasn't for any of the reasons others have mentioned.

In many cases, lambda functions simply improve readability of your code. Before lambdas when you call a method that accepted a function pointer (or function, or delegate), you had to define the body of that function somewhere else, so when you had "foreach" construct, your reader would have to jump to a different part of the code to see just what exactly you were planning to do with each element.

If the body of the function that processes elements is only few lines of, I would use an anonymous function because now when you are reading code, functionality remains unchanged, but the reader doesn't have to jump back and forth, the entire implementation is right there in front of him.

Many of the functional programming techniques and parallelization could be achieved without anonymous functions; just declare a regular one and pass a reference to that whenever you need to. But with lambdas ease of writing code and ease of reading code is greatly improved.

Comment: Very good explanation (+1). Lisp programmers have been aware of all this since 1958. ;-)

Comment: @Giorgio: Sure, but lisp programmers also had to buy special keyboards with reinforced open/close parenthesis keys :)

Comment: @DXM: not keyboards, they get additional input device that is kind of like piano pedals for opening and closing parenthesis ;-)

Comment: @DXM, vartec: Been doing some Scheme lately and I find the parentheses OK. Some C++ code can be much more cryptic (and I have much more experience with C++ than with Scheme). :-)

Answer (score 9):

Having been involved in the recent history here a bit, I believe that one factor was the addition of generics to Java and .NET. That naturally leads to Func<*,*> and other strongly typed computational abstractions (Task<*>, Async<*> etc.)

In the .NET world we added these features precisely to support FP. That triggered a cascading set of language work related to functional programming, especially C# 3.0, LINQ, Rx and F#. That progression influenced other ecosystems too and still continues today in C#, F# and TypeScript.

It helps to have Haskell work at MSR too, of course :)

Of course there were many other influences too (JS certainly) and these steps were in turn influenced by many other things - but adding generics to these languages helped break the rigid OO orthodoxy of the late 90s in large parts of the software world and helped open the door for FP.

Don Syme

p.s. F# was 2003, not 2005 - though we would say it did not reach 1.0 until 2005. We also did a Haskell.NET prototype in 2001-02.

Comment: Welcome! I used 2005 for F#, as that's the year reported in the F#'s Wikipedia article as the year of the first stable release. Would you like me to change it to 2003?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't meant to be a serious answer, but the question reminded me of a cool humorous post by James Iry - [A Brief, Incomplete, and Mostly Wrong History of Programming Languages](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html) which includes the following phrase:

"Lambdas are relegated to relative obscurity until Java makes them popular by not having them."

Comment: golden phrase :)

Answer (score 4):

From what I see most answers concentrate on explaining why functional programming in general made it's comeback and made it's way into mainstream. I felt this however doesn't really answer the question about anonymous functions in particular, and why they suddenly got so popular.

What has really gained the popularity, are [**closures**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). Since in most cases closures are throw-away functions passed variable, it obviously makes sense to use anonymous function syntax for these. And in fact in some languages it's the only way to create closure.

Why have closures gained popularity? Because they are **useful in event-driven programming, when creating callback functions**. It's currently the way of writing JavaScript client code (in fact it's the way of writing any GUI code). It's currently also the way of writing highly efficient back-end code as well as system code, as code written in event-driven paradigm is usually **asynchronous and non-blocking**. For back-end this became popular as solution to [C10K problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem).

Comment: Thanks for stressing that this question is not about functional programming (+1) because (1) the idea of a block of code that is passed around as an argument is also used in non-functional languages like Smalltalk, and (2) mutating state captured from the lexical context of a closure (as possible in many lambda implementations) is definitely **non-functional**. And yes, having closures, the step to anonymous closures is short. The interesting thing is that closures have also been well-known for a long time, and event-driven programming has been used (as far as I know) since the eighties.

Comment: But maybe it was only in the last few years that it became clear that closures can be used much more often than previously thought.

Comment: @Giorgio: yes, most of concepts that are currently used have been around for very, very long. Yet they haven't been used the way, they are used now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is the increasing prevalence of concurrent and distributed programming, where the core of object oriented programming (encapsulating changing state with objects) no longer applies. In the case of a distributed system, because there *is* no shared state (and software abstractions of that concept are leaky) and in the case of a concurrent system, because properly synchronizing access to shared state has been proven cumbersome and error-prone. That is, one of the key benefits of object oriented programming no longer applies for many programs, making the object oriented paradigm far less helpful that it used to be.

In contrast, the functional paradigm does not use mutable state. Any experience we gained with functional paradigms and pattern is therefore more immediately transferrable to concurrent and distributed computation. And rather than reinvent the wheel, the industry now borrows those patterns and language features to address its need.

Comment: Anonymous functions in some main-stream languages (e.g. C++11) do allow mutable state (they can even capture variables from the defining environment and change them during their execution). So I think that speaking about the functional paradigm in general and about immutability in particular is a bit out of the scope of the question being asked.

Comment: Having just read some of the feature notes for Java 8, one of the main goals of project lambda is to support concurrency.  And THAT immediately takes us to the mutability clusterbomb that all of these wonderful javabeans are going to run into.  Once Java gets lambdas (assuming it really does in the final release of version 8), they then need to address the immutable-by-default issue, *somehow* (it kind of destroys the language, thinking in Lisp - side effect free functions - instead of in COBOL - whack on DATA DIVISION / COPYBOOK)

Comment: Well said. The move away from mutable state make concurrency easier and technologies like cascalog and spark easily distribute functional programming across a cluster of computers. See http://glennengstrand.info/analytics/distributed/functional/programming for more detail as to how and why.

Answer (score 1):

If may add my €0.02, although I would agree with the importance of JavaScript introducing the concept, I think more than concurrent programming I would blame the current fashion of asynchronous programming. When doing async calls (necessary with the webpages), simple anonymous functions are so obviously useful, that every web programmer (i.e., every programmer) had to get very familiar with the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Another really old example of something akin to anonymous functions / lambdas is [call-by-name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-by-name#Call_by_name) in Algol 60.  Note however that call-by-name is closer to passing macros as parameters than passing true functions, and it is more fragile / harder to understand as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Here the ancestry to the best of my knowledge.

- 2005: Javascript has most recently brought higher-order programming with lambdas back into mainstream. In particular libraries like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org) and [jquery](http://jquery.com). One of the first of these libraries was [prototype.js](http://prototypejs.org) which predates jquery by about year. Prototype is based on the Enumerable module of Ruby, which leads us to…
- 1996: Ruby's [Enumerable module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) very obviously took inspiration from Smalltalk's collection framework. As has been mentioned by Matz in many interviews, which leads us to…
- 1980: Smalltalk uses a lot of higher-order programming and provides a collection API that makes heavy use of higher-order programming (eg, [GNU Smalltalk's Iterable class](http://www.gnu.org/software/smalltalk/manual-base/html_node/Iterable_002denumeration.html)). In idiomatic Smalltalk code you won't find any for loops but only high-order enumerations. *Unfortunately when Java when Smalltalk's collection framework was ported to Java in 1998 the higher-order enumerations were left out. That is how higher-order programming was phased out of the mainstream for the next ten years to come!* Smalltalk has many ancestries, but relevant to OP's question is LISP, which leads us to…
- 1958: LISP, obviously, has higher-order programming at its core.

Comment: Amiss, of course, is the whole ML ancestry. ML, SML, OCaml, Haskell, F#. That got to count for something..

Answer (score -1):

Anonymous functions are nice because naming things is hard, and if you only use a function in once place, it doesn't need a name.

Lambda functions have only recently become mainstream because until recently, most languages didn't support closures.

I would suggest that Javascript has pushed this mainstream. It's a universal language that has no way to express parallelism, and anonymous functions ease the use of callback models. Additionally popular languages like Ruby and Haskell have contributed.

Comment: "Lambda functions have only recently become mainstream because until recently, most languages didn't support closures.": This reasoning sounds a bit circular to me: being mainstream means that most languages support it. One could immediately ask "What triggered the popularity of closures in modern programming languages."

Comment: I know that Python does not have the best implementation of lambdas. But in terms of popularity, it probably contributed more than Haskell.